# CiviCRM Security Patch Needed warning still exists from older Civicrm Version?

Tags: upgrade, security

I've moved a CiviCRM installtation from 5.7.3 (LTS) up to 5.10.4 *latest.

However CiviCRM still gives the 'Security Patch Needed warning' which displayed when it was on 5.7.3.

Database updates, cache clear and cron have all run so bit unsure why this still displays?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: What is the civicrm version shown at the bottom of the page? Can you paste a screenshot of the footer?

Comment: 5.10.4. Doesn't believe there are any updates to complete and seems perfectly fine.  Just a bit odd the notification persists..

Comment: just to double check what happens if you go to civicrm/upgrade?reset=1 now

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Sorry for the slow reply.  Was nothing outstanding. It now seems to have picked it up, whether it was just caching or waiting for something to processed on cron or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% on the outcome however it may have been a cached message. Not sure on the process for these being cleaned up after an update.

I had previously cleared caches / run cron but didn't help.